# OpenCV: for mp4 files, saving movie works but with wrong codec

Tags: python, opencv, video, codec

I am making a video editor in Python with OpenCV, and testing different combinations of codecs and file formats. For this example, I'm focusing on `avi` and `mp4` formats. I have tried multiple different four-character codecs (http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php) and they all saved an actual movie I can play.

The confusing things is when I reload them and extract the codec from the movie, it turns out that only the movie saved as `avi` seems to have been saved using the original codec. Below I have a chart showing the codec used for encoding (created using `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc()`), and then the corresponding codec extracted from the video after loading it later (extracted using `get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC)`). I also am putting the size in MB in parentheses.

For avi (encoded -> extracted):

```
MJPG -> MJPG (3.9)
FFV1 -> FFV1 (12.3)
DIVX -> DIVX (0.7)
```

For mp4:

```
MJPG -> mp4v (3.9)
FFV1 -> avc1 (26.1)
DIVX -> mp4v (0.7)
```

So you can see that the encoding does not match for the mp4 file types, even though the file sizes *roughly* match up. The videos all look pretty much the same for avi versus mp4.

Is this metadata from the loaded movies not trustworthy for mp4, is the encoding not working for mp4 so it is picking a default, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you try to use combination of codec (how the video content is compressed) and container (the actual file format used to transport the compressed video (and usually audio, subtitiles,...) that are not compatible.

Comment: I thought this at first, but my understanding is these are different issues, that different codecs should be consistent with a wide array of containers (https://blog.filestack.com/thoughts-and-knowledge/complete-list-audio-video-file-formats/
).  Interestingly, when I tried *saving* using `AVC1` (or `avc1`) as the four-character codec, it didn't work for either file format.

Comment: It seems different backend for compression are used depending on the machine you execute opencv. Do you have fflmpef installed? https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#details

Comment: It is using `ffmpeg` on the back end.

Comment: What I would do then is "play" with ffmpeg command line argument to see if those combination are working. If yes then the issue might be on opencv usage of ffmpeg. Then having a look at the opencv code itself or raising an opencv bug is the good way forward.

Comment: Yes, this playing is exactly what I did -- see results of my play in my question. Are we now going recursive :)  My question is more why things worked the way they did: I listed a few possibilities in the final para of my question I'm curious if anyone knows.

Comment: Sorry, my understanding of your question was you did everything from opencv calls, that why I proposed to at least do an encoding using directly ffmpeg command line arguments. You are right though. I do not know why it does not work as expected ;-)

Comment: sorry you are right I did use OpenCV, but it uses ffmpeg on the back end. I should have been more clear.